# Integer solutions of $ x^4+34x^2 y^2+y^4=z^2$

Tags: diophantine-equations, integers

Now I'm trying to solve one problem, and already twice an expression of the form $a x^4+b x^2 y^2+a y^4 \,\,(x > y > 1)$ appears under the square root.

First was: $9 x^4 - 14 x^2 y^2 + 9 y^4$

Second: $x^4 + 34 x^2 y^2 + y^4$

I suppose that there will be other equations of this type.

Question: Are there integer solutions or a parametrization of equations$ a x^4+b x^2 y^2+a y^4=z^2$ in general, or of the variants proposed above in particular? Or maybe can the absence of solutions be proven?

Upd: No solutions

Second case: according to https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/0B14DEDE386776126F3B5A36CA325ECF/S0017089500007862a.pdf/x4-dx2y2-y2-z2-some-cases-with-only-trivial-solutions-and-a-solution-euler-missed.pdf (Thanks Will Jagy for link)

First case: $9 x^4 - 14 x^2 y^2 + 9 y^4$ can be written as  $(3(x^2-y^2))^2 +(2xy)^2=z^2$  Pythagorean triple. So $2xy=2ab, 3(x^2-y^2)=a^2-b^2$

From this: $3y^4+(a^2-b^2)y^2-3a^2b^2=0$ can be obtain.
Discriminant $a^4+34a^2b^2+b^4$ (Second equation of my question. Strange coincidence). So there is no rational roots.

Comment: Please, use MathJax to write math formulas: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4735/mathjax-better-way-to-prepare-a-math-stackexchange-question.  Also try to provide your own attempt to solve the problem, which will increase your chances of receiving an answer

Comment: The title equation can be written $$(x^2-y^2)^2+(6xy)^2=z^2$$ So $u=x^2-y^2, v=6xy, w=z$ is a Pythagorean triple.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  34 is done in Brown(section 3 on Applications of Concordant Forms), https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/0B14DEDE386776126F3B5A36CA325ECF/S0017089500007862a.pdf/x4-dx2y2-y2-z2-some-cases-with-only-trivial-solutions-and-a-solution-euler-missed.pdf

Comment: In both your cases, $a=a_0^2,$ $b+2a=c^2,$ for integer $a_0,c$ so they are both of the form $$(a_0(x^2-y^2))^2+(cxy)^2=z^2.$$ So they are both about Pythagorean triples of a particular form.

Comment: @WillJagy 
Thank you. Very usefull link.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you. I tried to solve 34 today but I couldn't. (According to the article linked in the comments, there is no solution). I'll try the second equation later.

Comment: For $9 x^4 - 14 x^2 y^2 + 9 y^4 = z^2$ solutions is $(x,y,z)=(n,n,2n^2)$ where $n\in \mathbb N$

Comment: @DmitryEzhov Unfortunately it must be x>y. And in this case  there is no solutions. (I'v prooved it last night.)

Answer (score 1):

Your equations are examples of *Elliptic Curves*. More precisely you can dehomogenise the LHS of your equation so that you are looking for rational points on the (affine) genus $1$ curves
$$ C_1 : z^2 = 9x^4 - 14x^2 + 9$$
$$C_2 : z^2 = x^4 + 34x^2 + 1$$

Now if you look for a few seconds you'll realise there are the points $(0,3)$ and $(0,1)$ on $C_1$ and $C_2$ respectively -- i.e., $C_1$ and $C_2$ are elliptic curves, just not in Weierstrass form. To resolve the rational points we put them in Weierstrass form and note that they are both isomorphic to the elliptic curves in the LMFDB $48a3$.

This curve has precisely $8$ rational points. On your original models, these correspond to the points $(x : z : y)$ (note the coordinate rearrangement)
$$\{ (1 : -3 : 0), (1 : 3 : 0), (-1 : -2 : 1), (-1 : 2 : 1), (0 : -3 : 1), (0 : 3
: 1), (1 : -2 : 1), (1 : 2 : 1) \}$$
and
$$\{ (1 : -1 : 0), (1 : 1 : 0), (-1 : -6 : 1), (-1 : 6 : 1), (0 : -1 : 1), (0 : 1
: 1), (1 : -6 : 1), (1 : 6 : 1) \}.$$

Here the colon means that these are the only solutions up to rescaling of the form $(ux, u^2z, uy)$.

Comment: When you say put them in Weierstrass form, is that transformation an isomorphism? I remember seeing some other answers transforming projective elliptic curves, but they are all isogenies or birational equivalences. If I want to preserve the group structure (in particular the order of the elements), how should I make the change of variables?

Comment: @flypig yes it is an isomorphism (under the correct viewpoint). The curves $z^2 = f(x,y)$ are *smooth* projective curves in the weighted projective space $\mathbb{P}(1,1,2)$ in particular when you put them in Weierstrass form you have a birational map between smooth projective curves - which can therefore be extended to an isomorphism. Note that the group structure of an elliptic curve depends on the choice of the identity. To put in Weierstrass form follow the proof that a smooth curve of genus 1 with a point is isomorphic to one in Weierstrass from - compute RR spaces of $2[O]$ and $3[O]$

Answer (score -2):

At first, it looks like the equation can be rewritten as a Pythagorean triple
$\space A^2+B^2=C^2\quad$ here shown by Euclid's formula:
$\quad A=(m^2-k^2) \quad B=2mk\quad C=(m^2+k)^2\space $ and a triple may be found given any legitimate value of $A,\space B, \space \text{or}\space C.$

$\text{Here we have}\quad(x^2-y^2)^2 + (6xy)^2 =z^2\space$ and $\space B= 6xy\ne 2mk\space$  so it is not a Pythagorean triple because it cannot quite be a right triangle. The best approach may be experimentation and observation.

\begin{align*}
x=0,\space y=0 &\implies z\in\mathbb{Z}^2
\\
x=y,\space\space \space  x,y>0 &\implies z=6n^2\space ,n\in\mathbb{N}\\
\not\exists \space x>y>1
\\
x=0,\space y=4 &\implies z=\pm8
\\
x=4,\space y=0 &\implies z=\pm8
\end{align*}

Comment: There might be multiple ways to write a number as the difference of two squares, for example $8^2-7^2 = 4^2-1^2$.